# how to load bitmap using easeljs?

Tags: javascript, bitmap, easeljs, preloader

I am trying to load bitmap using easeljs but its not working, please help me.

```
function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "assets/puli.png";

    var container = new createjs.Container();
    stage.addChild(container);

    bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
    container.addChild(bitmap);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
}

function tick(event) {

    if (update) {
        update = false; // only update once
        stage.update(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load your images using the LoadQueue Class form EaselJs:
take  a look at this--> http://www.createjs.com/Docs/PreloadJS/classes/LoadQueue.html

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
queue.addEventListener("fileload",onFileLoaded.bind(this));
var manifest = getManifest();
queue.loadManifest(manifest);

onFileLoaded = function(evt)
{
 var item = evt.item;
 var type = evt.type;
}

getManifest = function()
{
 var manifest = [
 {src:"/images/yourimage.png", id:"myimage"}    
 ];

 return manifest;
}

//create images
var myimage = new createjs.Bitmap(images.myimage);
```

Answer (score 1):

@CMS is right that preloading the content helps -- the issue you are seeing is likely that the image is not loaded when you update the stage, and it is only updating once.

You can use your approach in the original question, as long as you update the stage once the image is loaded. You can do this simply by waiting for a load event from the image. Something like this:

```
image.onload = function() {
    update = true;
    // OR
    stage.update();
}
```

Using PreloadJS is a better approach for a larger app, since it gives you way more control of when assets are loaded, etc -- but its not necessary to get your code working.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. 
Try this - I put the addChild and stage update in the onload event. 
Works for me.

```js
var stage, rect, img, greenRect;

function init() {
    stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");   
    rect = new createjs.Shape();
    img = new Image();
    img.src = 'green.jpg';
    img.onload = handleImageLoad;
}

function handleImageLoad(event) {

    greenRect = new createjs.Bitmap(img);
    stage.addChild(greenRect);
    greenRect.x = 100;
    greenRect.y = 100;
    stage.update();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this code from YouTube, and it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="easeljs.js"></script>      <!==load the EaselJS library==>
<script>
//this sample displays a bitmap file

var stage, img, map;        //declare global variables

function init() {
//this function is registered in the html body tag

    stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");   //create a Stage object to work with the canvas element

    img = new Image();                          //create an Image object, then set its source property
    img.src="my_photo.jpg";

    img.onload = handleImageLoad                //register a handler for the onLoad event
}

function handleImageLoad(event) {
//this function runs when the onload event completes

    map = new createjs.Bitmap(img);             //create a Bitmap object, then set properties
    map.x =50;
    map.y =50;

    stage.addChild(map);                        //add the Bitmap object as a child of the stage, then update the stage
    stage.update();
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">

    <!==add a canvas tag==>
    <canvas id="demoCanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works when the PreloadJS library is sourced

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="EaselJS/lib/easeljs.js"></script>      <!==load the EaselJS library==>
<script src="PreloadJS/lib/preloadjs.js"></script>  <!==load the PreloadJS library==>
<script>
//this sample displays a bitmap file

var stage;          //declare global variables
var img;
var map;
var queue;

function init() {
//this function is registered in the html body tag

    stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");   //create a Stage object to work with the canvas element

    img = new Image();                          //create an Image object, then set its source property

    img.onload = handleImageLoad                //register a handler for the onLoad event

    queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
    queue.addEventListener('complete', handleImageLoad);
    queue.loadManifest([
    id="img", img.src="my_photo.jpg"
    ])
}

function handleImageLoad(event) {
//this function runs when the onload event completes

    map = new createjs.Bitmap(img);             //create a Bitmap object, then set properties
    map.x = 0;
    map.y = 0;

    stage.addChild(map);                        //add the Bitmap object as a child of the stage, then update the stage
    stage.update();
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">

    <!==add a canvas tag==>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I recomend you AngularJS.
You have to call a function on HTML:

```
<body ng-init="initCanvas()">
        <center>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="602" height="447"></canvas>
        </center>
</body>
```

In JavaScript:

```
    var stage, image;
    var initCanvas = function() {
        stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

        image = new createjs.Bitmap("img/image.png");

        image.x = 0; image.y = 0; image.visible = true;

        stage.addChild(image);
        stage.update();
    };
```